# error inserting php to database using a jquery function option textarea

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Hi guys you have some idea about this codes, textarea submitted to database. because i have a connection.php but it is not inserting to database please help me using option textarea. Can you help me also for the phpmyadmin SQL what name, type, etc should i put, thanks

**select.html**

```
 <html lang="en">
    <title>NTF Catering Service</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">            </script> 
     <script src="js/js.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     </head>
   <body>
   <form action="submit.php" method="post">

   <select multiple="multiple" name="food" class="options" id="textarea">
         <option name="foodA"value="foodA">foodA</option>
           <option name="foodB" value="foodB">foodB</option>
              <option name="foodC" value="foodC">foodC</option>
                 <option name="foodD" value="foodD">foodD</option>
                     <option name="foodE" value="foodE">foodE</option>
    </select>


       <button type="button" id="copy" onclick="yourFunction()">Copy</button>
       <button type="button" id="remove" onclick="yourFunction()">Remove</button>

          <select id="textarea2" multiple class="remove" name="food">


      <input type="submit" name="submit" />
      </form>
       </select>
        </html>
```

**connection.php**

```
   <?php
   $dbhost = "localhost";
   $dbuser = "root";
   $dbpass = "";
   $db = "copy";

   $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
   mysql_select_db($db);
    ?>
```

**submit.php**

```
  <?php
    include 'connection.php';

     $foodA = $_POST['foodA'];
     $foodB = $_POST['foodB'];
     $foodC = $_POST['foodC'];
     $foodD = $_POST['foodD'];
     $foodE = $_POST['foodE'];


  if(!$_POST['submit']) {
      echo "please fill out the form";
       header('Location: select.html');
    } else {
              $sql = "INSERT INTO remove(food1, food2, food3, food4, food5) VALUES ('".$food1."', '".$food2."', '".$food3."','".$food4."','".$food5."');";
           mysql_query($link, $sql);
      echo "User has been added!";
        header('Location: select.html');

  }
  ?>
```

Comment: the `select`s need names and form is being closed before select is closed

Comment: @G.Mendes tnx for your reply but i already but names on the select area but still not inserting to db

Comment: Please update the code with the names in selects, the `$_POST` items in `submit.php` must have same names as the names given in the inputs for it to work

Comment: @G.mendes ok w8t tnx;)

Comment: @G.Mendes here already updated the codes

Comment: remember in your `submit.php` the `food` value will come as JSON probably as `$_POST['food']`, you will need to split it manually to get each value, it won't work if you get like this `$_POST['foodA']` and so on, for any doubts dump `$_POST` to check how its being received by the script

Comment: @G.Mendes so what will i change for $_POST? tnx

Comment: @user3211646 please tell us which plugin for multiselect you're using

Comment: @G.Mendes 
 here im using this jquery function

Comment: @G.Mendes 
 $(function(){
    $("#copy").on("click", function(){
        $(".options option:selected").each(function(){
           $("#textarea2").append('<option>'+$(this).text()+'</option>'); 
            $('option:selected', "#textarea").remove();
        });  
    });  
    $("#remove").on("click", function(){
        $(".remove option:selected").each(function(){
           $("#textarea").append('<option>'+$(this).text()+'</option>'); 
            $('option:selected', "#textarea2").remove();
        });  
    });  
});

Answer (score 2):

Your missing the

```
<form action="submit.php" method="POST">
```

From the start of the form.

Also to debug SQL issues more in depth, id put:

```
if (mysql_errno()) { 
  echo "MySQL error ".mysql_errno().": ".mysql_error()."\n<br>When executing:<br>\n$query\n<br>"; 
exit;
}
```

right before the header() function after mysql_query(). Post the error if it occurs and we should be easily be able to debug what is wrong.

Comment: ill try this i think i have a form action?

Comment: sry codes has been cut:) already edited it, i try putting names on each food but still not inserting to db

Comment: Did you get any MySQL error when submitted? What gets shown when you click submit?

Comment: nothing happen? just reload the page

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use two `selects`, to send items from first to second, so the second will be posted to `script.php`, so first of all you need to name only the second `select`as `food[]` since it's a multiple select, also the `copy` function must be changed to make sure goes through post correctly, close the select `#textarea2` before `form` is closed for no side effects, form code will be changed to:

**select.html**

```
 <form action="submit.php" method="post">
   <select multiple="multiple" class="options" id="textarea">
     <option value="foodA">foodA</option>
     <option value="foodB">foodB</option>
     <option value="foodC">foodC</option>
     <option value="foodD">foodD</option>
     <option value="foodE">foodE</option>
   </select>


   <button type="button" id="copy">Copy</button>
   <button type="button" id="remove">Remove</button>

   <!-- note how multiple select name must be set -->
   <select id="textarea2" multiple class="remove" name="food[]"> 
   </select>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" />
  </form>
```

and the script part added selected so it will be processed:

```
<script>
$(function(){ 
  $("#copy").on("click", function(){ 
    $(".options option:selected").each(function({
      $("#textarea2").append('<option selected>'+$(this).text()+'</option>');
      $('option:selected', "#textarea").remove(); 
    });
  }); 
  $("#remove").on("click", function(){ 
    $(".remove option:selected").each(function(){
      $("#textarea").append('<option>'+$(this).text()+'</option>');
      $('option:selected', "#textarea2").remove(); 
    }); 
  }); 
});
</script>
```

that being changed, php will treat textarea2 as an array of options, one way to retrieve them could be:

**submit.php**

```
foreach ($_POST['food'] as $food){
    $food == "foodA" ? $foodA = $food : $foodA = '';
    $food == "foodB" ? $foodB = $food : $foodB = '';
    $food == "foodC" ? $foodC = $food : $foodC = '';
    $food == "foodD" ? $foodD = $food : $foodD = '';
    $food == "foodE" ? $foodE = $food : $foodE = '';
}
```

Make sure the data sent is the one your **database** expects, any doubts use Rehan's debug suggestions.

Comment: ill try this also tnx:) ill reply soon

Comment: so in submit.php i will remove all? and change it for foreach? or what will i change for the foreach? tnx

Comment: just replace the $foodA - $foodE block with the `foreach` block